# Haskell show should I exclude the list based on other List?

Tags: list, haskell

I have two lists; one is the list I want to exclude from the other list,
It is like this one

```
a::[String]
a = [["A1","B2","C5"],["A3","B1","C2"]]
```

And I have another list that I want to exclude every element that contains either one of three elements on `a`

```
b :: [[String]] 
b = [["A1","B1","H5"],["A3","C2","B1"],["A1","B2","H5"],["H2","H3","B2"],["H5","B1","H4"]]
```

The expected result would be :

```
[["H5","B1","H4"]]
```

Here is my approach:

```
excludeList ::[[String]]-> [[String]] -> [[String]]
excludeList a b = filter (any (`elem` b)) a
```

I know the code above will keep the elements that contain any of the elements in `list1`, but I don't know how to do it the opposite way, using `not`? But wherever I put not, my IDE always gives me an error. How can I fix it? And it seems `elem` can't handle the `[[String]]` type, what should I do?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should include the code which causes the error and the error itself.

Comment: You mention `list1` in the text, but not in the code. Please correct the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about using `not`, but you might use it incorrectly. `not` should be used in composition to the existing function that is passed to `filter`:

```
filter (not . (any (`elem` b))) a
```

Or by using `de Morgan Laws`:

```
filter (all (`notElem` b)) a
```